# My Ruby Anagram not working correctly

Tags: ruby, anagram

i was given an assignment to write an Anagram program
below is what i came up with

```
 class Anagram

    attr_accessor :anagram_value
    def initialize(value)
        @anagram_value = value
    end

    def matches(*collection)
        matches = []

        matches = collection.select  do |word| 
            (word.length == @anagram_value.length) ? is_an_anagram?(word) : false 
        end


        return matches
    end

    def is_an_anagram?(word)


        return get_word_ord_sum(word) == get_word_ord_sum(@anagram_value)
    end

    def get_word_ord_sum(word)
        sum = 0
        word.split("").each { |c| sum += c.ord }
        Areturn sum
    end

end
```

while the Above works using the following cases, Surprisingly.

```
it "detects multiple Anagrams" do
    subject = Anagram.new("allergy")
matches = subject.matches('gallery', 'ballerina', 'regally', 'clergy', 'largely', 'leading');

   expect(matches).to eq ['gallery', 'regally', 'largely']
end
```

it actually fails the following

```
it "no matches" do
  subject = Anagram.new("abc")
  matches = subject.matches("bbb")
  expect(matches).to eq []
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `97 + 98 + 99 == 98 + 98 + 98`. Aka, the sum of the character numbers does not uniquely map to the histogram of a given string.

A way to fix it would be to map `get_word_ord_sum` to something else. For example, the *"smallest"* anagram will do. However, note it's `O(nlgn)`:

```
word.chars.sort.join
```

---

**EDIT**: Expanding on the idea to use `Array#group_by`, replace `get_word_ord_sum` with:

```
word.downcase.chars.group_by(&:itself)
```

Now you will get a histogram-like hash, and since order of keys while comparing hashes doesn't matter, you will get your desired result in `O(n)`.

Comment: yea.. i know.. that's what I'm finding solution for

Comment: @OyebanjiJacobMayowaPyJac, if you already knew that, why did you said *"Surprisingly"*? Anyway, if you want a `O(n)` solution just use `Array#group_by` and ensure that the count for each occurring character is the same for both strings.

Comment: pls, can you explain more ?

Comment: it works for some cases but fails this                                                  it "detects Anagrams case-insensitively" do
    subject = Anagram.new("Orchestra");
    matches = subject.matches('cashregister', 'Carthorse', 'radishes')

    expect(matches).to eq ['Carthorse']
  end

Comment: @OyebanjiJacobMayowaPyJac, you never said it should be case insensitive. Anyway, I will add the `String#downcase`, which will fix the issue.

Comment: @OyebanjiJacobMayowaPyJac, I did. See the updated version of the `group_by` solution.

Comment: it works for some cases but fails this it "does not detect a word as its own Anagram" do
    subject = Anagram.new("banana");
    matches = subject.matches('Banana')

    expect(matches).to eq []
  end .... Thanks for your time

Comment: @OyebanjiJacobMayowaPyJac, dude... You just keep adding new requirements that are not reflected in the original question. To ensure that a word is not considered an anagram of itself, just add a `&& word != @anagram_value` after the equality check in `is_an_anagram?`.

Comment: I must thank you for your time. thanks.. but it still not work and adding the above check created alot of failures..... These are the tests ==> http://pastebin.com/3yC9JrLv

Comment: @OyebanjiJacobMayowaPyJac, what are the failures? Give an example with the error output.

Comment: @OyebanjiJacobMayowaPyJac, and this is after doing `return get_word_ord_sum(word) == get_word_ord_sum(@anagram_value) && word != @anagram_value`?

Comment: @OyebanjiJacobMayowaPyJac, please make an effort to read. `Areturn`. This obviously wouldn't happen if you changed the body of `get_word_ord_sum` to `word.downcase.chars.group_by(&:itself)`

Comment: Here is what i have => http://pastebin.com/1zfHNwNX .... It would do great help helping to fix it.. Thanks

Comment: @OyebanjiJacobMayowaPyJac, simply replace the body of `get_word_ord_sum` with `word.downcase.chars.group_by(&:itself)`. Aka instead of `sum = 0; word.split("").each { |c| sum += c.ord }; Areturn sum`

Comment: @OyebanjiJacobMayowaPyJac, SO is not a *"write my homework"* service. Not only did you extend the original question 5 times, but you also systematically refuse to try and think. The reason a single comparison didn't work was because the test was testing `banana` against `Banana`. Again, simply use `String#downcase` to make the comparison case insensitive. I changed it, [here is a version that passes all of your tests](http://pastebin.com/Yc9cyzx8).

Comment: Thanks your version works... I'm not on SO for  any __write my homework service__. I'm here to see if i can get a solution that would work based on ASCII characters sum. I've seen a similar solution that looks like your version earlier before posting my code. Thanks anyway...

Comment: @OyebanjiJacobMayowaPyJac, I answered your initial question and instead of aknowledging it as correct, you kept extending it. Also you didn't solve a problem a second time when you have seen the same problem the first time, meaning you didn't put any effort to think. And even after I solved all of your problems, you still haven't marked the answer as correct...

Comment: guess you're not "THINKING" in my direction... I need ASCII sum solution not the chars sorting + down-casing solution..

Comment: @OyebanjiJacobMayowaPyJac, I already explained to you that this can NOT be done with simple ASCII sum, because the int values wont uniquely identify the string's histogram. It's like asking *"how can I encode 2 bytes of information in 1 byte"*.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
words =  ['demo', 'none', 'tied', 'evil', 'dome', 'mode', 'live',
          'fowl', 'veil', 'wolf', 'diet', 'vile', 'edit', 'tide',
          'flow', 'neon']

groups = words.group_by { |word| word.split('').sort }
```

Return groups:

{["d", "e", "m", "o"]=>["demo", "dome", "mode"], ["e", "n", "n", "o"]=>["none", "neon"], ["d", "e", "i", "t"]=>["tied", "diet", "edit", "tide"], ["e", "i", "l", "v"]=>["evil", "live", "veil", "vile"], ["f", "l", "o", "w"]=>["fowl", "wolf", "flow"]}

```
groups.each { |x, y| p y }
```

Returns each value:

["demo", "dome", "mode"]

["none", "neon"]

["tied", "diet", "edit", "tide"]

["evil", "live", "veil", "vile"]

["fowl", "wolf", "flow"]